# Matlab, inverse of the image function

Tags: image, matlab

I have a series on .png images, which were created by Matlab running 'image' on series on mxn matrices. In doing so, it applied the default colormap (jet).
I now need to get the data back from the images (the data itself was lost). As I understand it, the image function takes my mxn matrix, and a colormap, and uses it to generate an mxnx3 tensor (of RGB values). Is it possible (aside from just searching through the colormap like a lookup table), to get Matlab to go from the image, and, based on the colormap used to generate it, reconstruct the data.

This can certainly be done, since the mapping from the original data to the RGB values is linear, based on the colormap, but I can only think of using the colormap as a lookup table. Is there a sort of reverse-image function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data **is lost** in the conversion from an arbitrary `m`-by-`n` matrix to an "image":
Matlab **shifts** and **scales** your data to range [0..255] and **quantizes** it to 256 discrete levels.
Even if you are willing to neglect the quantization error, there are still the unknown shift and scale factors you need to recover in order to convert the mapped color image to the original matrix.

You can use [`rgb2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html) to convert the image to the quantized [0..255] values:

```
 [x map] = rgb2ind( img, 256 );
```

But you cannot convert `x` to your original data since you do not know the proper scale and shift.

Comment: Can you state where this 256 discrete levels are defined? Reading the documentation I believe it should be 64 levels as default.

Comment: I think could also do `rgb2ind( img, jet )`

Comment: @bdecaf you might be correct. I did not fully investigate this case, I assumed Matlab uses 8bits/pixel from the indexed image, but I might be wrong here.

Comment: @Dan nice idea. more specific solution for this example, may produce more robust results.

Comment: The images do have a colour bar, so the scaling would not be a problem. The data are all positive, with a minimum of zero (that much I can remember), so the shift shouldn't be a problem either. I am aware that any data reconstructed would be quantised, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that lookup quite easily using the second output of `ismember` and some `reshapes`:

```
[~,x] = ismember(reshape(Img,[],3), jet, 'rows');
reshape(x, size(Img(:,:,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a tool that does exactly what you do. Some data is definetly lost Png has at most 48bit per pixel (practically you have much less as you are restrained to the colormap) while double as Matlab uses has 64bits. But it seems to me if you use default `jet` colormap wou will just have 64 levels.

Practically I think you can get usable results. Jet is supposed to be a HSV colormap. So maybe `rgb2hsv` will give you a mappable hue value. Using the interpolate functions it should be possible to calculate back. But that would basically be a lookup.